# How to format text within Qt Widget

Tags: python, pyqt

A code below creates a simple window with `QLabel`. `textDict` is nicely formatted into string variable `info`. But this beautiful formatting is all lost as soon as the text is assigned to QLabel (or any other QWidget).

**Question**: How to preserve a text formatting.

Here is the screenshot showing the text on a widget and as a result of `print()`

[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

textDict={'Python': 'Is a widely used general-purpose, high-level programming language', 'Its_design': 'philosophy emphasizes code readability, and its syntax', 'allows': 'programmers to express concepts in fewer lines of code than would be possible in languages such as C'}

label=QtGui.QLabel()
info=''
for key in textDict: info+=(key+str(textDict[key]).rjust(150-len(key),'.'))+'\n'    
label.setText(info)
label.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Please notice that the text should be right-justified. It is completely missing in Qt QLabel.

## EDITED:

Finally with the huge help of **Gerrat** (Thanks!):
Monospace font should be used to achive this trick. I have tested with twos and it works:
`font-family: Lucida Console` and `font-family: Courier New`
Syntax:

`label=QtGui.QLabel()`

`label.setStyleSheet(" font-size: 10px; qproperty-alignment: AlignJustify; font-family: Courier New;")`

[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

textDict={'Python': 'Is a widely used general-purpose, high-level programming language', 'Its_design': 'philosophy emphasizes code readability, and its syntax', 'allows': 'programmers to express concepts in fewer lines of code than would be possible in languages such as C'}
class AppWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AppWindow, self).__init__()
        mainWidget=QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(mainWidget)
        mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        mainWidget.setLayout(mainLayout)   
        for key in textDict:
            info=(key+str(textDict[key]).rjust(150-len(key),'.'))+'\n'  
            label=QtGui.QLabel()
            label.setText(info)
            label.setStyleSheet(" font-size: 10px; qproperty-alignment: AlignJustify; font-family: Courier New;")
            mainLayout.addWidget(label)

window=AppWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use a [subset of HTML](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/richtext-html-subset.html) to style it.  One way to accomplish what you want would be that instead of `'\n'`, you could use `<br>` for line breaks.

**EDIT :**  One reason it's messing up is that it's not using a monospaced font. Your dots are not using up the same space as a regular character.  'Every text editor' you're trying is using a monospaced font...pick a proportional font for one of your editors and watch it mess up.  The gist is that, instead of using HTML, you could instead pick a fixed-width font.

Comment: Interesting that every text editor I copy-paste the output of Python formatting displays the text properly. I can't find the way to even replicate what Qt widget does to the formatting! There are 150 characters in each of three lines. And yet QLabel (designed to work with text) messes up things beyond recognition.

Comment: That's interesting! What monospaced font would you recommend? (so Qt widgets render a text formatting similar to text editors)...

Comment: Got it! Just posted it under Edited section of my question! Thanks! It took me hours! I am glad it is over. Thanks for your help! Monospaced font was the answer!